# Submit Form and return values using HTML / JQuery / PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

need your help for this ... My homepage have 3 divs, #Header, #Content, #Footer. All the other pages are being opened inside the #Content div. In one of those pages I have a form with two select lists and one submit button. Just want to click the button and then return another page into the #Content div, showing the values that I select before. Like this:

The origin is: 1
The destiny is: 1

But this code returns the following ...

```
Notice: Undefined variable: origin in ...
Notice: Undefined variable: destiny in ...
```

**Note: This is working if I don't open the page inside the #Content div**

**my Html:**

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="values.php" method="POST">
    <select id="origin" name="origin">
        <option value="0" selected>-- Select Origin --</option>
        <option value="1">Portugal</option></select>
    <select id="destiny" name="destiny">
        <option value="0" selected>-- Select Destiny --</option>
        <option value="1">Lisboa</option></select>
    <input id="btSubmit" name="btSubmit" type="submit" value="search!">
</form>
```

**my Function:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btSubmit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $('#myform').attr('action');
        var method = $('#myform').attr('method');
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: $('#myform').serialize(),
        success: $('#content').load(url)
        });
    });
});
```

**my values.php page:**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['origin']) || isset($_POST['destiny'])) 
    {
        $origin = $_POST['origin'];
        $destiny = $_POST['destiny'];
    }
    echo 'The origin is:' . $origin . '<br>';
    echo 'The destiny is:' . $destiny;
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call `load` again - you have already called it essentially with `$.ajax` and received the results. So you need just display them in the `content`:

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#content').html(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use success callback function correctly. Accept response in callback method and set it in your div

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#content').html(data);
}
```

Additionally, You should perform your operation with form submit event.

```
$('form#myform').on('submit', function (e) {
```

instead of

```
$('#btSubmit').click(function(e) {
```

Comment: thanks for your help. Regarding the change to the Submit button, it doesn't work ... When I press the button, nothing happens, not eaven a message error ...

Answer (score 0):

As Andrei mentioned you have to use

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#content').html(data);
}
```

because calling   `success: $('#content').load(url)` triggers a new `GET` request. When GET request reaches php code `$_POST` is not set and your variables are not initialized  so you get the  message from php:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: origin in
```